# ReplaceAll regex in xml string

Tags: java, xml, regex

I'm trying to manually add some prefixes to my xml string, for this I need a particular java expression that I just can't seem to find, basically this my string:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mediabericht xmlns:mb="http://www.mediabericht.org"><inhoud>Randominhoud 22</inhoud><netwerk>Twitter</netwerk><datum>1408625886036</datum><film>Gladiator</film></mediabericht>
```

I want to add prefixes to my elements, so it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <mb:mediabericht xmlns:mb="http://www.mediabericht.org"><mb:inhoud>Randominhoud 22</mb:inhoud><mb:netwerk>Twitter</mb:netwerk><mb:datum>1408625886036</mb:datum><mb:film>Gladiator</mb:film></mb:mediabericht>
```

I want to do a few replaceall's but so far I had no luck

The first regex I need to solve is `< but not <? or </` and use the replaceAll function to replace these by `<mb:` (the prefix)

Then the second replacement I've handled:

```
String prefixedString = xmlString.replaceAll("</", "</mb:");
```

Comment: do you want to add spaces before `<mediabericht`?

Comment: Uhm no, why would I do that?

Comment: i can't find the differences in the input and  the expected output.

Comment: Apologies I didn't edit the second one, it should have the prefixes

Comment: The proper way to do this is with a parse of the XML tree, not with a regex.

Comment: I know, but I asked this question on stackoverflow before with no answers, so I figured I'd just do this the dirty way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first regex I need to solve is `< but not <? or </` and use the replaceAll function to replace these by `<mb: (the prefix)`

This can be solved using [*look-ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String prefixedString = xmlString.replaceAll("<(?![/?])", "<mb:");
```

Comment: After replacing this error it finally worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with  [*Lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> The Lookaround (zero length assertions) actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.

```
<(?!\/|\?)
```

Replacement : `<mb:`

OR

```
(?<=<)(?!\/|\?)
```

Replacement : `mb:`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oE7rZ9/2)

Patten explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    <                        '<'
  )                        end of look-behind
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    \/                       '/'
   |                        OR
    \?                       '?'
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Sample code:

```
System.out.println("<abc></abc>".replaceAll("(?<=<)(?!\\/|\\?)", "mb:"));
```

OR simply use `<\b` as suggested by @Avinash Raj in below comments where `\b` is used as **word boundary**.

```
System.out.println("<abc></abc>".replaceAll("<\\b", "<mb:"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I should really spend an afternoon learning patterns, so far I've always looked 'em up or asked for them on stackoverflow

Comment: @user You could simply use this `(?<=<)\b` http://regex101.com/r/oE7rZ9/3

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, that's also correct. Nice one. OR keep it simple `<\b`

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything with only one regexp:

```
String prefixedString = xmlString.replaceAll("(</?)([^?])", "$1mb:$2");
```

will correctly replace the opening and closing tags (and ignore the `<?xml>` tag) in only one `replaceAll()` call.

Comment: EDIT: Nvm this works, thanks, that makes it even more simple